# Swift try the returns for fileManager.copyItem

Tags: swift

I understand that I can try for fileManager.copyItem.

But I want to return whether the operation is successful or not. Therefore I tried to the following:

```
            do {
                try let isSucessful = fileManager.copyItem(at: originURL, to: destinationURL)
                return isSucessful
            }
            catch let error {
```

Here is the documentation confirming that copyItem(atPath:toPath:) does return a Boolean value: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412957-copyitem

But "Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Bool'" do How can I return if the operation is successful or not for a try operation?

Comment: Ok, it says that. But sure isn't on paragraph further.

Comment: Well, as I say, it isn't the docs but the truth that's important. I make my living by not believing the docs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, `copyItem` does not return any value (despite the rather confusing documentation), so you gain nothing by assigning its "result" to a variable (your `isSucessful`). Perhaps you mean this sort of thing:

```
do {
   try fileManager.copyItem(at: originURL, to: destinationURL)
   return true
} catch {
   return false 
}
```

That answers the question "was there an error or not?", which is what you seem to be asking.

A one-liner version (assuming you've no more to do in this method) would be:

```
return nil != (try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: originURL, to: destinationURL))
```

Comment: However, it might be better to return a Result instance, because it can carry the actual error if there is one.